# Picturing Electron scattering in periodic lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrons

I'm reading *Electrons in a Periodic Potential* from The  Oxford Solid State Basic. There is a particular point which I'm able to see mathematically but not quite able to picture.

---

Consider electron in periodic potential $V(\mathbf{r})=V(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})$. It turns out after a short calculation, that

> Any plane-wave state $\mathbf{k}$ can scatter into another plane-wave state $\mathbf{k}'$  only if these two plane waves are separated by a reciprocal lattice vector.

I'm not getting this, I mean pictures. Suppose I have an electron I throw it toward this periodic potential then what would happen? What we mean by electron will scatter into another if plane waves are...... As there is only one plane wave, the one incident. What would happen if the condition not satisfied? Is that mean the electron will just go through the potential?

Consider a one-dimensional case, I sent the electron with momentum $k$, and suppose $G=2\pi /a$ then Can you demonstrate above by varying $k$? I mean what will happen if a certain electron wave is sent?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually misled. You cannot "send an electron of momentum $k$" into this lattice.

The eigen function of the periodic structure is described by the Bloch wave function.The Bloch form of wave function must be spreaded into the whold lattice:
$$
  \psi_k(x) = \sum_n e^{ikx} u_k(x). \tag{1}
$$

Where the index $n$ runs over all lattice sites, and $u_k(x)$ is a periodic function: $u_k(x+na) = u(x)$. This Bloch function allow you to determine the band energy E(k), by connecting the lattice with a phase factor $e^{ika}$ for two neighbor lattice. Otherwise, we don't know how to find the eigen function and its eigen value in a infinite periodic system.

Therefore, you cannot put in an electron with a definite $k$. If you replace $k$  by $k+G$ (shifted a reciprocal lattice). The Eq. (1) remains a Bloch form of wave vector $k$:

\begin{align}
 \psi_{k+G}(x) &= \sum_n e^{i(k+G)x} u_{k+G}(x)\\
&= \sum_n e^{ikx} \left\{ e^{iGx}u_{k+G}(x)\right\}\\
&= \sum_n e^{ikx} u'_{k}(x)
\end{align}
Where $ u'_{k}(x)=e^{iGx}u_{k+G}(x)$ is also an periodic function:

$$ u'_{k}(x+na)= e^{inGa} e^{iGx}u_{k+G}(x+na)=e^{iGx}u_{k+G}(x)=u'_{k}(x)$$

Though you cannot throw in an electron of $k$, you can described an electron with a localized function (e.g. Gaussian function). This localized function is a combination of many Bloch functions.
$$
  \Psi(x, 0) = \sum_{\frac{-\pi}{a} \le k \le \frac{\pi}{a}} a_k \psi_k(x)
$$

The localized function (wave package) will then spreaded onto the more and more of the lattice as time evolutes:
\begin{align}
   \Psi(x, t) = \sum_{\frac{-\pi}{a} \le k \le \frac{\pi}{a}} a_k e^{iE(k)t/\hbar}\psi_k(x)  
\end{align}

Comment: I don't find it useful, Here I'm trying to picture.

Comment: I find your comment hard to understand. Where is here?

Comment: The title of the question is how I can picture electron scattering. ALL you have written are more and more math, which zi already have.

Comment: Do you mean the scattering of electron by the periodic potential? and What is an electron is sent of "k"?